# Generating a dynamic password reset link

Tags: java, spring-boot

To reset my password I want to send the user a link to site/account/{hash} where {hash} is a hash of the user's password and a timestamp.
I have the following code to hash only the email and have a readable link:

```
    String check = info.mail;
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    String checkHash = Base64.encodeBase64String(md.digest(check.getBytes()));

    if(checkHash.equals(hash)){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Password reset to: " + info.password);
    }else{
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hash didn't equal to: " + checkHash);
    }
```

The problem is that when I convert this to Base64 it may include / signs what will mess up my links and checking of the hash.
I can simply replace any unwanted signs by something else after the hashing but is there some other way to have your hash only include a certain part of codes?

Also I know the returns are still sent unsafe but this is just for testing and debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RFC 3548 specifies a variant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548#section-4) often called "base64url" specifically designed for that purpose. In this variant, `+` and `/` are replaced by `-` and `_`.

Java 8 has built-in support with the new [Base64 class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html). If you're stuck with an older version, the [Base64 class of Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) can be configured to be url safe by using the `new Base64(true)` constructor.

Other options might be:

- Don't use Base64, but transfer the bytes as hexadecimal
  representation (which will not contain any special characters):

  ```
   String checkHash = toHex(md.digest(check.getBytes()));
  ```

  with

  ```
   private static String toHex(byte[] bytes) {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       for (byte b : bytes) {
           sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
       }
       return sb.toString();
   }
  ```
- Use URL encoding/decoding on the generated hash (that's what you already know)